# OneSignal api sometimes respons "false" sometimes send proper response

Tags: api, onesignal

I use oneSignal api for push notofication.
But Api didn't response every time.
Parameters are always the same.

Sometimes api response false, sometimes give proper respnse...

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Have you found any solution yet?